# Operate on columns with the same name in the second level in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with a multi-index on the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('a', 'status'): [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                   ('a', 'value'): [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
                   ('b', 'status'): [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                   ('b', 'value'): [2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
                   ('c', 'status'): [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
```

My goal is to multiply all the `value` columns by a scalar, or add a scalar to them. I have been struggling to find the appropriate expression to use with direct indexing or `iloc`, but can't seem to find the right one. Here are some failed attempts:

```
>>> df[(None, 'value')] += 2
...
KeyError: 2

>>> df.iloc[:, (None, 'value')] += 2
...
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I imagine it's possible, though not very elegant to make a mask or index of the columns, so I tried:

```
>>> df.columns.levels[1] == 'value'
array([False,  True])
```

This does not help with the five actual columns that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [*slicers*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) :

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), "value")] +=2

#another variant
# df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, "value"]] += 2
```

Output :

```
print(df)

       a            b            c
  status value status value status
0    0.1   3.1    0.1   4.1    0.1
1    0.2   3.2    0.2   4.2    0.2
2    0.3   3.3    0.3   4.3    0.3
```

Comment: So close yet so far away. Very nice find. I didn't even know what to look for :)

Comment: Yes, you were one *step/slice* away from getting it done! You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `df.where()` is an option:

```
m = df.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'value'

df.add(2).where([m]*df.shape[0],df)
```

or

```
df.add((df.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'value')*2)
```

Output:

```
       a            b            c
  status value status value status
0    0.1   3.1    0.1   4.1    0.1
1    0.2   3.2    0.2   4.2    0.2
2    0.3   3.3    0.3   4.3    0.3
```